# Why does anchor href show full path for fragment?

Tags: javascript, html, fragment, anchor

I have anchor tags with `href` containing only a fragment. I have a click handler assigned. When I clicked on the link, after the handler finished, the page loads the page that's a level higher.

Here are the facts:

1. The page is at `http://domain.com/app/path_component`
2. The page defines `<base href="http://domain.com/app/">`
3. Page contains: `<a href="#fragment">`...`</a>`
4. jQuery sets a click handler: `$('a').on('click', handler)`
5. `.htaccess` directs server handling to the PHP app on the server at …`/app`

I was not returning false, nor calling e.stopPropagation() or e.preventDefault(), so I understand that the browser would do its default thing and handle the href. What I do not understand is why it loaded another page?

In tracing through my handler, I saw that this.href is "http://domain.com/app/#fragment". That would explain why the parent page is loading, but I don't understand why it was that page and not http://domain.com/app/path_component#fragment"?

The only way I could see the original href was to check the href attribute directly. I wanted to allow the page load if it should be necessary, but prevent it when it was only a fragment, so I wrote the handlers return as:

```
return $(this).attr('href')[0] != '#';
```

Why was this necessary? I thought the default handling for a fragment is not to go back to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A browser handles shortlinks by concatenating them with a link assigned in the base tag, so if you assigned `<base href="http://something.com/">` all shortlinks and relative sources (i.e. `<img src="...">`) will be handled relatively to the `base`. The `<base>` primely intended to make your web-pages easy portable to another site.

So as a solution you need to assign anchor path relatively to base:

```
<a href="path_component#fragment">
```

Another way is js based anchor:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.location.hash='fragment';">fragment</a>
```

One of solutions is to generate the base node using javascript at start of page and appending it to `<head>` as a child:

```
<script>
  var currPage = window.location.href;

  if (document.getElementsByTagName("base").length === 0) {
        var base = document.createElement("base");
        base.setAttribute("href", currPage);
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(base);
    }
  else {
    document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].setAttribute("href", currPage);
  }

</script>
```

It should work, but as I mentioned above, if you use relative path for image sources, you should start their links with `../` (i.e. `<img src="../images/image.gif">`) for getting absolute path based on parent page.

Comment: I set <base> for the purpose you describe, but I didn't think it'd affect stand-alone fragments, since they usually don't even trigger a call back to the server. I have to reframe my understanding of this.